# How to create multi party webrtc connections, just for dataChannels?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I just want to share light weight data between mesh of rtc peers. But not able to figure out programmatically how I can create a mesh network and create multiple dataChannels.

Comment: Post any comments in the comments section of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new peerconnection on each user for each new user that you get. Then you will have to create data channels for each peer connection.
EX. peers A B C

- peer A has two RTCPeerConnection one to C and one to B
- peer B has two RTCPeerConnection one to A and one to C
- peer C has two RTCPeerConnection one to A and one to B

ps. EACH of these CONNECTIONS have a data channel.

Alternative: A->B->C->A you connect them in a chain, which is computationally better, but it is harder to manage messages and destinations

Comment: Yeah I was trying to do the same but it was not working. Do you have any code examples, kindly share

Comment: Sorry I'm beginner but can we add two remote  description in A ? One for B and one for C

Comment: no read the answer again, you need a PEERCONNECTION for each peer you are trying to connect to, so A has an array of two peerconnections one for a and one for B, would love to share code but I can't, and also would not be helpful, I must add that what you are trying to do is pretty hard and I got a lot of headaches  along the way